# wget download limited by http address

Tags: http, recursion, directory, wget

I want to download a website using it's address as a download limiter.

To be precise..
The website address is `http://das.sdss.org/spectro/1d_26/`
It contains around 2700 subsites with data. I want to limit the recursive download of all files in a way that I can download sites from:

```
http://das.sdss.org/spectro/1d_26/0182/
```

to

```
http://das.sdss.org/spectro/1d_26/0500/
```

Using [this](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-download-multiple-files-with-wget.html) tutorial I have made a wget command:

```
wget64 -r -nH -np -N http://das.sdss.org/spectro/1d_26/{0182..0500}/
```

but the last bit of address gives me 404 error.

Is there a mistake in my command or is the tutorial faulty?

P.S. I know it's possible to achieve with -I lists but I want to do it this way if it's possible.

Comment: What OS are you running? Those special characters are most likely meant to be interpretted by a bash shell. If you're not running bash on *nix/cygwin, that probably won't work.

Comment: This command was run on Windows 7 64bit as my wlan drivers for Ubuntu are quite poorly made and I tend to loose connection,

Comment: There's no equivalent function in CMD or Powershell, I'm afraid. Cygwin with a bash shell should "just work".

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Looks like all I have left is a list...